# Reference static files in django in .py files ( NOT in templates)

Tags: python, django, static

I've been like an hour searching how to reference static files in django, but I only found how to do it in templates. 
In my project, I succeeded in referencing static files in my templates, but I DON'T want to do it in templates, I want to do it in my .py files.

I think that i have to import static from somewere, I've tried with this:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

And trying to reference it like this

```
'<a href=/url> <img  src="{{ STATIC_URL }}image.png" ></a>'
```

I've tried all possible combinations like

```
{% static image.png %}
{{static image.png}}
```

and so on...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
'<a href=/url> <img  src="{0}" ></a>'.format(static("image.png"))
```

Note that `django.templatetags.static` is actually a function. The template engine calls that function when you use the template tag.

Comment: @Danidestroyer Could you accept one of the answers? That way, other people will know this question has been answered.

Comment: For me this shows path correctly but imgs in admin never load

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the actual file on disk, you can use the *finders* class of the *staticfiles* app:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
>>> finders.find("icons/exclamation.svg")
'C:\\<project folder>\\<project name>\\<app name>\\static\\icons\\exclamation.svg'
```

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#finders-module)

Answer (score -2):

You can read django configuration to get [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#static-url) which contains URL base part for static files:

```
from django.conf import settings
import urlparse

print '<a href=/url> <img src="%s"></a>' % urlparse.urljoin(settings.STATIC_URL, 'image.png')
```

Comment: Code snippets on their own are not very informative. Please explain what the code does, why you wrote it that way, and how you expect it to work

Comment: I've add a link to documentation

Comment: This doesn't work with various static file storage backends